# Disable cellular radio on iPad when sleeping?

Tags: ios, ipad, battery, cellular-data

I want to save battery and not be logged in CDRs when my iPad is idle (besides, I have two phones that are online constantly so I am already notified when I receive mail or other updates), hence I want to automatically disable cellular radio when the iPad is locked/screen is turned off. Any solutions for this? I am prepared to jailbreak it if necessary.

Comment: Just asking — why don't you turn it off?

Comment: 1. Because I forget it. 2. Because it takes a long time to boot it.